# How to connect with microsoft sql sever with ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm totally new to ASP.NET. I wanted to create small API. I tried to connect that API with Microsoft Sql Server. But it gives an error which is

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddMvc' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code

My `Startup.cs` file is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
//using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.ExistingDb.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using myApp.Models;

namespace myApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=(JKCS-AREBY\SQLEXPRESS)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

That error is indicate in `app.UseMvc();` . Can you anyone help  me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after the services.AddDbContext …
just add services.AddMvc()
(just as the error Msg suggested )

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=(JKCS-AREBY\SQLEXPRESS)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
            services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
 services.AddMvc()
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain more sir?

Comment: What additional explanation are you looking for? You must call `services.AddMvc()`. The exception tells you as much, as does this answer.

Comment: the 404 is regardless to your question. you need  ask new question with relevant code